# Neo4J Cypher - Unwinding nodes from a path variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have seen examples of unwinding lists, but not of unwinding a list of paths. How can I find, for example, all of the shortest paths between one type of node and another, and return or get the nodes that are found, in this example the nodes specifically being `b`.

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a: person)-[:PARENT_OF]-(b: person))
UNWIND nodes(p) ... //get all of the b nodes
RETURN b
```

Note: I would like to use b within the query for another purpose (omitted), and therefore need to unwind the path into a list of `b` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

After matching all shortest paths, if you just want the `b` nodes as a result, you may simply `RETURN b`. I don't believe you need to UNWIND it, since `b` is clearly identified in your MATCH

Edit:

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a: person)-[:PARENT_OF]-(b: person))
WITH collect(b) as bees
UNWIND bees as b
//do something
return b
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, I would like to use b before the return. I simplified my query a lot. I will update my question.

Comment: Ah ok, do you need to use just b, or the entire path?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to see all `person` nodes that have an incoming `PARENT_OF` node from another `person` node. If so, this should work:

```
MATCH ()-[:PARENT_OF]->(b:person)
RETURN DISTINCT b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a: person)-[:PARENT_OF]-(b: person))
with nodes(p) as nodes
with nodes[size(nodes)-1] as b
return b
```